# Ubuntu thinks I have a manually installed driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.04

Ubuntu seems to think I have a manually installed driver when I am using the default drivers (Nouveau) and therefore I cannot switch to the other Nvidia drivers. I want to install them this way and not manually so is there any way I can make Ubuntu realise I do not have any manually installed drivers.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried in a terminal `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that earlier and then Ubuntu just boots to a black screen so I have to go to recovery and uninstall it all again.

Comment: Did you install or remove any of the nvidia drivers ? If so, perhaps rebooting will fix the problem.

Comment: I rebooted after installing with no luck and rebooted several times once I had removed and purged them.